# Close all Chrome browser or Firefox browser instances at once

Tags: browser

After a good session of web usage I often have 10 or more Chrome or Firefox instances open at once.  Closing each browser is tedious.

Is there an orderly way to shut down all browser instances at once without killing the process?

Is shutting down the browser by killing the process unhealthy in any way?  I mostly run Windows for web surfing.

Comment: Which OS?  "Killing" the process is only bad if it has unsaved data.

Comment: If Windows, right-click on the taskbar icon for the browser and select "close all windows"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under each browser, if you go to their respective menus, eg **File** menu for Firefox and **Customize and Control Google Chrome** (the wrench icon) for Chrome, click the **Exit**.

It will shutdown all instances.

Comment: Works!  Firefox: File > Exit  Chrome:  Wrench (options) > Exit

Answer (score 3):

This works for all browsers, if you replace chrome.exe with the appropriate image name:

```
taskkill.exe /IM chrome.exe /T
```

or if you want to force termination:

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM chrome.exe /T
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: +1 because it works, but it's not an orderly shutdown so I prefer @surfasb's answer since Chrome apparently allows a shutdown of all browser instances using the UI

Comment: @steampowered : In the example where /F is not used, then taskkill will send a request to the program to close, and the program can cleanly close itself.  How is this not an orderly shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter, i tried the above solution but it does not work with /T option, An error comes, so try with /F option which means forceful and it works

```
taskkill.exe /IM chrome.exe /F
```

This way all instances of a process/browser can be killed at once by running the above command on command prompt